# Conditional probability - finding a single event

Tags: probability, statistics

Context:
 $P(L) = 0.1$,  $P(M | L) = 0.45, P(M | L') = 0.51$ 
$M =$ Male, $M' =$ Female, $L =$ Left handed, $L' =$ Right handed.

> **1.** Find $P(M)$.

So I knew I had $P(M | L)$ and $P(M | L')$ so I tried to add the two as it would cover both outcomes that a male is left handed and a male is right handed which gives total males. So am I correct in doing this? 
$$P(M | L) + P(M | L')$$
Otherwise can you please show me the correct way to do this as I am a little unsure.

> **2.** Find $P(L | M')$, the probability that a person is left handed given that they are female.

I figured $P(M') = 1- P(M)  = 1- 0.96$ so $P(M') = 0.04$ 
and I figured $P(L \cap M') = 0.1 \times 0.04 = 0.004$.

Therefore $P(L | M') = 0.004 / 0.04$ and I ended up getting $0.04$ which meant the events are mutually exclusive or my answer is wrong..
Can you please help me with these two questions as I am unsure of my methods.

Comment: With conditional probability questions you need to think how you can write an event as a union of mutually exclusive events. L and L' are mutually exclusive so you can write M = (M and L)or(M and L'). Then P(M) = P(M and L) + P(M and L'). Now use the definition of conditional probability and values given to work out each piece. If you manage Q1 then Q2 should be ok.

Comment: do you know $P_L$ and $P_{L'}$?

Answer (score 1):

If you find the formulae too mind-bending, suppose you have $1000$ people with these probabilities representing proportions.

Then you would have $100$ left-handed people, of which $45$ would be left-handed males and $55$ left-handed females.

You would also have $900$ right-handed people, of which $459$ would be right-handed males and $441$ right-handed females.

So there are $45+459=504$ males, representing a proportion $\frac{504}{1000}=0.504$ of the total population.

There are $55+441=496$ females, so the proportion of females who are left-handed is $\frac{55}{496}\approx 0.1109$.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's my suggestion: for 1) use the law of total probability
$$
P_M=P_{M|L}P_L + P_{M|L'}P_{L'}
$$
Once you've done that, use $P_{M'}=1-P_M$ for 2):
$$
P_{L|M'}=\frac{P_{M'|L}P_L}{P_{M'}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

1) $$P\left(M\right)=P\left(M|L\right)P\left(L\right)+P\left(M|L^{c}\right)P\left(L^{c}\right)$$

2) $$P\left(L\mid M^{c}\right)=\frac{P\left(L\cap M^{c}\right)}{P\left(M^{c}\right)}=\frac{P\left(L\cap M^{c}\right)}{P\left(L\right)}\frac{P\left(L\right)}{P\left(M^{c}\right)}=P\left(M^{c}\mid L\right)\frac{P\left(L\right)}{1-P\left(M\right)}=\left(1-P\left(M\mid L\right)\right)\frac{P\left(L\right)}{1-P\left(M\right)}$$